# How can I make the background blink or flash continuously until the button is pressed again, then it will flash or blink 2 new random colors

Tags: ios, swift

How can I make the background color flash 2 new colors continuously every time the button is pressed? Right now it just shows 2 colors but they don't blink or flash continuously.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let colors: [UIColor] = [
        .systemYellow,
        .systemGreen,
        .systemPurple,
        .systemPink,
        .systemRed,
        .systemBlue,
        .systemOrange,
        .black,.gray
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapButton() {
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
        }, completion: { finished in
            print("another animation! - 1")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1/2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors.randomElement()
            }, completion: { finished in
                print("another animation! - 2")
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

[image: Screen starts black, but once button is tapped, screen transitions between random colors. After bring tapped again, screen transitions between 2 new random colors.]

You can use the `[.repeat, .autoreverse]` options to repeat and reverse the color animation.

Then, because the button is a subview of the view that you are animating (user interaction for the view and its subviews are normally disabled during animations), you can add the `.allowUserInteraction` option to allow pressing the button again.

```
@IBAction func didTapButton() {
    let color1 = self.colors.randomElement()
    let color2 = self.colors.randomElement()
    
    self.view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    self.view.backgroundColor = color1 /// set to color1
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .allowUserInteraction]) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = color2 /// now animate to color2, reverse, then repeat
    }
}
```

Comment: how can we remove the label "button" when the button is pressed